# Java PopUp Menu & Floating BOX on the Top

Tags: java, windows, swing, popup

I'm currently in a stagnant (stuck) point here.

First of all, let me clearly telling you about my case here.
I have Java Swing App that use a Pop Up menu.
I create some **'N' items of Menu Items** There. 
I wanted to have **1 Box area at the top** of it, it will **show 1 Single Image**. 
I'm planning to use either **another JPopup Menu** over there, or maybe... **Floating JPanel**.... I'm not sure which one is good. 
Thus, I need the fixed coordinate to placed them on. Now i'm confused.

Anyway, Here is the [Screenshot.](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/w2lwb)

My Question is...

- How do I make the GreenBox appeared on the top of Those Menus?
- Should I calculate how many 'N" menu Items multiply by Font Size as
  the fixed coordinate?

  Or...
- Something else I forgotten? What is the appropriate step to overcome
  this case?

I'm still
Digging for answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [JWindow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html) (required `JFrame`, this `JFrame` never couldn't be visible), this container is undecorated by default, or maybe un_decorated `JDialog`, with `ModalityTypes` or `setModal`

Comment: thanks. I hv another idea to solve the coordinate location. :D